# What bit of the xfce DE controls the wallpaper?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment, wallpaper

I want to have the glmatrix xscreensaver running as my desktop background, which works well on pure openbox, but in xfce I need to kill whatever is is running the root window (as far as I understand). What process is this in xfce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit you are looking for is `xfdesktop`.

You should be able to disable it in the session manager (`xfce4-session-settings`)

Comment: '/usr/lib/xscreensaver/glmatrix -root' doesn't do anything, even after 'killall xfdesktop'. hmmm.

Comment: Session manager will try to respawn it several times - you either have to kill it several times to convince it not to do that any more. Or try shutting it down from the session manager.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Window Manager Tweaks and there the last tab is Compositor.  Uncheck it.