# In XFCE, how do I set an animated GIF as a desktop background?

Tags: xfce, wallpaper, gif

This should be a simple task, but I can't figure out a way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not specific to XFCE, Mplayer is able to play video, or animated gifs on the background, running the following on startup should result in the gif being rendered, on loop, in the background.

`mplayer -loop 0 -fs -zoom location-of-animate-gif.gif -rootwin`

Comment: X11 error: BadAccess during XSelectInput Call
X11 error: The 'ButtonPressMask' mask of specified window was probably already used by another application (see man XSelectInput)
X11 error: MPlayer discards mouse control (reconfiguring)

Comment: Oh right, what happens if you try something like xwinwrap (https://shantanugoel.com/2008/09/03/shantz-xwinwrap/) there seems to be videos of people successfully using that on XFCE.

Comment: Or you might be able to disable the session-manager then run mplayer as root https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92504/what-bit-of-the-xfce-de-controls-the-wallpaper

Comment: I've also seen xwinwrap and unsuccessfully tried it. It's just too outdated. The guide you linked, from 2008, even calls it old! If you have a more up to date guide maybe this would be an option.

Comment: The solution was kill `xfdesktop` and then run this command. Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: Yea nice, glad you got it working!